# Form that when updating current client, removes child table information connected to parent table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my Spring-boot, Java, and Thymeleaf application, I have a form that is filled out once with new client information and is saved to SQL database table. When you want to edit this client's information, and click save, it ends up saving/updating the info but also removing information in a SQL child table, called ResourceWebsiteAccess. I can't tell if it is updating the info and there's a problem with the child table, or if it is just replacing all the clients information and therefore deleting the child table information. Any ideas what is going wrong and how to go about fixing it?

Here is some of the html form:

```html
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" th:action="${clientEndpoint}" method="post" th:object="${client}" class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane" id="prospect-profile">
        <div th:replace="prospectProfile :: prospect-profile"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane" id="affiliates">
       <div class="row">
           <h4>Affiliate Competency</h4>
           <br/>
           <div th:replace="affiliates/personalLines :: personal-lines"></div>
       </div>
       <hr/>
       <div class="row">
           <div th:replace="affiliates/commercialLines :: commercial-lines"></div>
           </div>
           <hr/>
    </div>
   <input id="submitButton"  type="submit" value="Save" name="save" class="btn btn-success finish" data-loading-text="Saved!" disabled="true"/><br/>
</form>
```

This is the controller action that occurs when you hit the save "button".

```html
@RequestMapping(value="/saveClient")
@ResponseBody
public JSONObject saveClient(Model model, @ModelAttribute(value="client") Client client)
  {
        Boolean saved=false;
        JSONObject response=new JSONObject();
        Client clientBeforeUpdate=clientRepository.findById(client.getId());
        if (clientBeforeUpdate!=null && !clientBeforeUpdate.getStatus().equals("active") && client.getStatus().equals("active"))
            client.setOnboardedDate(LocalDate.now());
        else if (!client.getStatus().equals("active"))
            client.setOnboardedDate(null);
        try{
            client=clientRepository.save(client);
            saved=true;
            response.put("clientId",client.getId());
        }catch (DataAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.put("error",e.getLocalizedMessage());
            response.put("cause",e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        response.put("success",saved);
        return response;
    }
```

Client Repository:

```html
@Transactional
public interface ClientRepository extends CrudRepository<Client,Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {

    Client save(Client entity);

    List<Client> findByPrincipleNameContaining(String principleName);

    List<Client> findByNdaSent(Boolean ndaSent);

    List<Client> findByLegalNameContaining(String legalName);

    List<Client> findByYearsExperienceContaining(String yearsExperience);

    List<Client> findByLicenses(String licenses);

    Client findById(Long id);

    void delete(Client entity);

    List<Client> findAll();

    @Query("SELECT c FROM Client c Where c.status = 'active' AND ((c.contractExecuted=false OR c.agencyLicenseReceived=false OR c.eoReceived=false OR c.w9 =false OR c.directDepositCommissionAgreement=false) OR c.licenses!='Accident & Health' AND (c.producerAppointmentForm=false OR c.prepaymentAuthorizationAms360=false))")
    List<Client> findClientsMissingDocs();

    List<Client> findByNdaSentAndNdaSentDateBetween(Boolean ndaSent,LocalDate start,LocalDate end);

    List<Client> findByContractSubmittedAndContractSubmittedDateBetween(boolean b, LocalDate startOfMonth, LocalDate now);

    List<Client> findByStatus(String prospect);

}
```

Here is some of client.java, the model for the form.

```html
@Entity
@Table(name="Client")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Client {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ClientId")
    private Long id;
    ...
    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "client")
    private List<Employee> employees= new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "client")
    private List<VendorService> vendorServices=new ArrayList<>();


    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JoinColumn(name="client")
    private List<ResourceWebsiteAccess> resourceWebsiteAccess=new ArrayList<>();

    public List<ResourceWebsiteAccess> getResourceWebsiteAccess() {
        return resourceWebsiteAccess;
    }

    public void setResourceWebsiteAccess(List<ResourceWebsiteAccess> resourceWebsiteAccess) {
        this.resourceWebsiteAccess = resourceWebsiteAccess;
    }
}
```

Here is the model for the ResourceWebsiteAccess, this doesnt have an individual controller, but it does have its on Repository

```html
@Entity
@Table(name = "ResourceWebsiteAccess")
public class ResourceWebsiteAccess {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  micrositeLink;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ResourceWebsiteAccessId")
    private Long id;
    private String micrositeLink;
    private String partnerPortalLink;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "client")
    private Client client;
  ...    
}
```

How I am adding the information to the child table, via a form, that uses this controller:

```html
    @RequestMapping(value="/settings/client/{id}")
    public String links(@PathVariable("id")Client client, Model model){
        ResourceWebsiteAccess access= accessRepository.findByClient(client);
        if (access==null)
            access= new ResourceWebsiteAccess();

        model.addAttribute("client",client);
        model.addAttribute("newUser",new ResourceWebsiteUser());
        model.addAttribute("users",repository.findByClient(client));
        model.addAttribute("access",access);
        return "settings";
    }
```

ResourceWebsiteAccess Repository:

```html
@Transactional
public interface ResourceWebsiteAccessRepository extends CrudRepository<ResourceWebsiteAccess,Long>,JpaSpecificationExecutor {
    ResourceWebsiteAccess findByClient(Client client);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having, is that you are updating all fields, including those that are coming as null from your form. What you really want to do, is update only those values that were modified. To do this, you can use Hibernate's  `@DynamicUpdate` annotation on your entity.

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name="Client")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Client { ... }
```

You can read more about this in the following [blog](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-exclude-unchanged-columns-generated-update-statements/).

Another way to achieve what you are trying to do, is fetching the client by it's id and then set the new values with the ones you just received from your form.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveClient")
@ResponseBody
public JSONObject saveClient(Model model, 
@ModelAttribute(value="client") Client client) {
    Boolean saved=false;
    JSONObject response=new JSONObject();
    Client clientBeforeUpdate=clientRepository.findById(client.getId());
    if (clientBeforeUpdate!=null && !clientBeforeUpdate.getStatus().equals("active") && client.getStatus().equals("active"))
            clientBeforeUpdate.setOnboardedDate(LocalDate.now());
    else if (!client.getStatus().equals("active"))
            clientBeforeUpdate.setOnboardedDate(null);
    try{
        // Set the rest of the needed changes from your new client.
        clientBeforeUpdate=clientRepository.save(clientBeforeUpdate);
        saved=true;
        response.put("clientId",client.getId());
    }catch (DataAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.put("error",e.getLocalizedMessage());
        response.put("cause",e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    response.put("success",saved);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Alain, thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately both of these are not working for me. Any other ideas/ would you like to see any other portion of the code?

Comment: One question, when you update your client, is the list of **ResourceWebsiteAccess** null or empty? With your current configuration, if the list is null or empty, it will delete the children. This is due to `orphanRemoval=true`. This last element will delete any child that lost it's reference to it's father. So if the list is null when you save it, it will then delete the orphans. If this is the case, then try doing this `client. setResourceWebsiteAccess(clientBeforeUpdate.getResourceWebsiteAccess());`.

Comment: So I was wondering if the issue is return response... The cause I think is triggered right before the last line to return response. The clientBeforeUpdate  is shown holding all the resourceWebsiteAccess info, but it is not being saved (or returned) in the JSON object called response.      But, when debugging, the client model "resourceWebsiteAccess" is null but the clientBeforeUpdate is not null. So maybe instead, this means something is wrong with my client model not setting the resourceWebsiteAccess ?

Comment: Yeah, clientBeforeUpdate should have the info, but what about `client`, which is the model coming from the form? Because, if you are saving that one, you won't notice any change on `clientBeforeUpdate`, because it is still on memory, but on the DB the changes should be reflected after the save. Just to be sure, remove `orphanRemoval=true` and let's see what happens.

Comment: Now I am confused. I removed the orphanRemoval = true, and kept in both changes you suggested in your first comment, and it has fixed the problem. So very exciting you fixed it, but could you please explain, was this a hibernate issue or a java issue?... or Both? Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Ok, here is the thing, `orphanRemoval=true` is used to delete children when they lose their father. This is an Hibernate thing. So, when you were updating your client, if you didn't check if your children list was null or empty, it would automatically delete the children, because they would be left without a father. 

Now, `@DynamicUpdate` is used when you only want to update the fields you really did modify and ignore those that are null.

The other change, was purely to avoid having null fields. Since you were fetching the class by it's ID and then only modifying the fields you wanted.

Comment: If you have any doubt, please let me know.

Comment: so I realized, it isn't deleting anything from ResourceWebsiteAccess because it's not actually saving. It's doing a temporary save, but when you exit out and get back in, it's the old information.

Comment: But the changes made to client are persisted? Or do they also go back to it's old self? If so, the transaction is not being committed.

Comment: And more importantly, is the issue still alive? :)

Comment: The changes made to client return to the old information. So it looks saved, but when you go to the home page, then get back in to the client's info, it is the old information again. So it is not actually updating the database. I think that is because we need this original line of code client=clientRepository.save(client); because there is no clientBeforeUpdate in the SQL db.

Comment: Ok, do you mind updating your code with the current changes? That change will work, keeping the DynamicUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

Since you were saving ResourceWebsiteAccess separately add insertable and updatable false in @JoinColumn

```
@OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JoinColumn(name="client",insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private List<ResourceWebsiteAccess> resourceWebsiteAccess=new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding @DynamicUpdate to the model, removing OrphanRemoval= true; in the model, and adding client.setResourceWebsiteAccess(clientBeforeUpdate.getResourceWebsiteAccess());to the controller.
These three steps fixed my issue and now everything is displaying. 
Thanks to @AlianCruz